# Nginx analyze CNAME chain

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system

let say I have DNS setup in a way that: `www.test.com` points with `CNAME` to `test.my-main-platform.com` and `test.my-main-platform.com` point to server where we have Nginx.

`www.test.com  --> test.my-main-platform.com  --> nginx`

For example on Nginx server I have

```
server {
  listen                80;
  location / {
    return 200 "hello from $http_host";
  }
}
```

when I do `curl http://www.test.com` I get `hello from www.test.com`

when I do `curl https://test.my-main-platform.com` I get `hello from test.my-main-platform.com`

**My question is this**: Is in Nginx a variable/module that I can use so that when I do `curl http://www.test.com` I'll get `hello from www.test.com via test.my-main-platform.com`

That means:

```
server {
  listen                80;
  location / {
    return 200 "hello from $http_host via $xxxxxxxxxxxx";
  }
}
```

> so what can I use instead of `$xxxxxxxxxxxx` so I detect the DNS chain

Comment: Nginx doesn't care. The browser looked up the domain name and resolved it to an IP address. The Nginx server is contacted using the IP address with the Host header set to the domain name in the original URL.

Comment: and is there evena a way how to detect it? E.g. if I build my own proxy server in some programming langue

Comment: You can do a DNS lookup but it's time consuming and will hammer the response time. What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to leverage CNAME for some other purpose?

Comment: I'm creating portal where user can create website. I want to allow users to connect custom domain to their website. You add a domain and portal generate "DNS target" e.g. you add domain `www.customdomain.com` I generate you `xxxx-xxxx-xxx.portal.com` so you need to add Cname `www` point to  `xxxx-xxxx-xxx.portal.com`  Now I could just `proxy_pass` everything to `portal.com` but it's extra layer of protection to check if `customdomain.com` points to the right DNS target  ( simmilar way how Heroku does this https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-)domains#configuring-dns-for-subdomains) . T

Comment: ...why the -1 ? It's genuine on topic question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing within nginx itself which would allow this behaviour, because nginx does not do DNS lookups for the contents of the Host header.

Comment: fair enough, I'll handle this on application level not on proxy level. Thx all for help